# ''to infinitive'''

Tags: grammar

'' I ***woke up to*** ***find*** ***the doctor lifting*** me very carefully into my own bed.
it was good to be back in my familiar bedroom, with a warm fire and candle-light.''
Jane Eyre oxford press

What kind of structure is it?
and what is the meaning of it ?(woke up to find the doctor lifting)

Comment: Please edit the title of your question, and the description, to match the piece of usage you would like explained. I suspect you just want “woke up to find” explained, but a strange fragment of the rest of the sentence to your question (“...the doctor lifting...”) has been added.

Answer (score 1):

There is a pattern here: You enter some position and then you find something. The position you enter may be “I’m awake”, “I can see”, “I’m in some place”, and we say

I woke up to find...

I opened me eyes to find...

I opened the car door to find...

I went on the stage to find...

In this case what she found was that the doctor was lifting her carefully. Together:

(I woke up) (to find) (the doctor lifting me).

Similar: I opened my eyes to find the sun shining in my bedroom. I opened the car door to find the seats full of bread crumbs. I entered the stage to find the audience waiting impatiently.